# Sort table by clicking on the column header

Tags: reactjs, sorting, html-table

I'm new to ReactJS. I have created a table with 2 columns. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination'

const Table = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [sorting, setSorting] = useState({ key: "name", ascending: true });

    const pageItemCount = 15
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0)
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getUsers(search);
            setUsers(response.data.users);
            setPageCount(Math.ceil(response.data.users.length / pageItemCount))
            setCurrentUsers(response.data.users.slice(0, pageItemCount))
        } catch (error) { }
    }, [search]);


    /**************************************** */
    useEffect(() => {
        const currentUsersCopy = [...currentUsers];
    
        const sortedCurrentUsers = currentUsersCopy.sort((a, b) => {
          return a[sorting.key].localeCompare(b[sorting.key]);
        });
    
        setCurrentUsers(
          sorting.ascending ? sortedCurrentUsers : sortedCurrentUsers.reverse()
        );
    }, [currentUsers, sorting]);
    /*************************************** */

    function applySorting(key, ascending) {
        setSorting({ key: key, ascending: ascending });
    }

    /************************************** */

    const changePage = (i) => {
        setCurrentPage(i)
        const startItem = ((i - 1) * pageItemCount) + 1
        setCurrentUsers(users.slice(startItem - 1, (pageItemCount * i)))
    }

    const handleChange = (event, value) => {
        changePage(value);
    }

    return (
        <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>
            <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center'>
                <div>
                    <svg className='relative top-10 right-3' width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M14 5H20" stroke="#79899e" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                        <path d="M14 8H17" stroke="#79899e" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                        <path d="M21 11.5C21 16.75 16.75 21 11.5 21C6.25 21 2 16.75 2 11.5C2 6.25 6.25 2 11.5 2" stroke="#79899e" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                        <path d="M22 22L20 20" stroke="#79899e" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                    </svg>
                    <input type='text' className='my-3 py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-sm text-text-secondary shadow-sm focus:ring-2 ring-text-secondary rounded-md w-full rd500:w-120' placeholder='search ..' onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} value={search} />
                </div>
                
                <div className="flex justify-center">
                    <select className="form-select form-select-sm
                    my-3 py-2 pl-15 pr-2 text-sm text-text-secondary shadow-sm rounded-md w-full
                    focus:ring-2 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none " aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                    <option selected value="1" onClick={() => navigate('/')}>users</option>
                    <option value="2" onClick={() => navigate('/ext')}>other users</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>



            <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>phone</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {currentUsers.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.phone}</td> 
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Pagination className="mt-2 pb-20" dir='ltr' page={currentPage} count={pageCount} onChange={handleChange} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

I'm trying to sort this table by clicking on each column header. I tried to apply the solutions suggested in [link1](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/sortable-tables-react/) and [link2](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-react-sortable-table/), but I have not been successful yet. How can I do this?

Edited: I edited my code and added the full code of my table.

Comment: At first add to you column headers `onClick` function and pass name or phone as params. Then sort your `currentUser` array by passed param, and `setCurrentUser(sortedArray)`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to sort this table by clicking on each column header.

One of the possible solution to achieve this type of functionality is to store current state of the sorting. To do this we can use `useState` hook

```
const [sorting, setSorting] = useState({ field: 'name', ascending: false })
```

As you can see, `useState` function accepts default value. In our case the default value will be the sorting default state. The `field` property tells which column to sort by, and `ascending` prop says in which order it should be sorted.

Next, we need to set event handlers to each header of the column.

```
 <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
   <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('name', !sorting.ascending)}>name</th>
   <th className='p-2' onClick={() => applySorting('phone', !sorting.ascending)}>phone</th>
 </tr>
```

By clicking the column header we call the function `applySorting` which says what column should be sorted.

```js
 function applySorting(key, ascending) {
   setSorting({ key: key, ascending: ascending });
 }
```

The last thing thing we need to do is to sort your data stored in `currentUsers` variable.

This part of the code is tricky a bit, because it uses `useEffect` hook. You can read the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to understand how it works.

Let's say this function will be called by React everytime you change the current state of your sorting variable.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // Copy array to prevent data mutation
    const currentUsersCopy = [...currentUsers];

    // Apply sorting
    const sortedCurrentUsers = currentUsersCopy.sort((a, b) => {
      return a[sorting.key].localeCompare(b[sorting.key]);
    });

    // Replace currentUsers with sorted currentUsers
    setCurrentUsers(
      // Decide either currentUsers sorted by ascending or descending order
      sorting.ascending ? sortedCurrentUsers : sortedCurrentUsers.reverse()
    );
  }, [currentUsers, sorting]);
```

I created this example on codesandbox where you can play around with this approach. [Link to working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-taussig-hq32qd?file=/src/Table.js:418-754)

I hope you enjoy learning React!

Comment: Thanks. Since I had a `useEffect` hook before, is it OK to add a new one? I added another one and now my table content is not displayed for me.

Comment: You can add as many useEffect hooks as you want. All they do is prevent code from executing on each component re-render. It runs only when dependencies are changed.

Comment: So why the content of the table is not displayed in spite of the fact that they are added to the database?

Comment: It's quite difficult to give you advice without seeing actual code. Could you share your code somehow?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and added the whole code.

Comment: I just reviewed your code and noticed that your `useEffect` hook depends on `search` variable. It means that everything inside this hook will be called only if this parameter will change. Try to type something inside your search input (data will appear in table) or move the call to external data into another `useEffect` hook. 

I created another codesandbox example. See https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-wind-t7zg72?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: I don't think that problem is because of another `useEffect` hook. I removed that `useEffect` (the one that relates to search bar) to see if it causes this problem, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my suggestion. If you entirely remove the `useEffect` hook that fetches your data that should be shown in the table you will not be able to see it (No fetched data == no data to display). I would suggest you to debug your code more precisely. Try to check my last codesandbox and read comments.